# Java Binary to Integer

Tags: java

I looked a couple of different way to convert binary to integer in JAVA.
But I couldn't figure out why this works?

```
int res = 0;
res += 1 << 1;
```

The res turns out to be 2, I know it shifts towards left 1 bit and became 10 in binary. But I'm confusing how it converts from binary to integer, i want to know the mechanism.

Thanks

Comment: Everything on the computer is binary. When you print it to System.out it converts it to base 10.

Comment: There is no conversion, since there is no binary primitive in Java; `res` is an `int`.

Comment: an `int` is already a 32-bit signed value i.e. it's already binary and you can't change that.  Any notion that it is anything other than binary is just to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up some terminology first. What you believe to be an integer is actually a number in the [base 10 notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal), which in case of Java is a [natural number](http://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html) that is represented using the ten digits from 0 to 9 (hence base 10).

In [binary notation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html) we are dealing with just two digits instead to represent all natural numbers. Both binary (base 2) and decimal numbers (base 10) are integers.

**Digit shifting is multiplication or division by the base of the number**

The bit shifting effect you observed can be easily explained using base 10 numbers you are already familiar with. Imagine you have a strip of square fields pre-filled with `0`s. In each field you can write a digit from 0 to 9, and lets assume these fields are called "*bits*". You write the number `7` into that strip aligned to the right hand side:

```
0|0|0|0|0|7
```

Imagine that whole strip represents the integer `7` now. What bit shifting effectively does, is moving those digits in that strip either to the left or the right, while filling up the previously occupied spots with `0`s. Imagine, we are shifting our `7` to the left by one spot:

```
0|0|0|0|7|0
```

By shifting the number to the left we practically performed a quick multiplication by `10` (remember, that is the *base* of our numeral system we're dealing with here).

When you shift that number to the right by one spot, you perform a division by `10`.

**Bit shifting is multiplication or division by 2**

The same applies to binary numbers, the dominant storage format for numbers in computers. Binary numbers are comprised of just two digits, 1s and 0s.

Just take a quick look at the following table for getting a better understanding of binary numbers:

```
+-------------------+
| Decimal | Binary  |
+---------+---------+
| 0000001 | 0000001 |
| 0000002 | 0000010 |
| 0000003 | 0000011 |
| 0000004 | 0000100 |
| 0000005 | 0000101 |
| 0000006 | 0000110 |
| 0000007 | 0000111 |
| ...     | ...     |
+---------+---------+
```

We perform multiplications by 2 when we shift the number in our strip to the left, and we perform divisions by 2 when we shift the number to the right. Just check out the table, and look up the decimal number 1. Multiply it by 2 and look at the binary representation. Multiply that again by 2 (decimal 4) and look at the binary notation. The binary digit `1` just moves to the left one by one due to the multiplication by two.

Answer (score 0):

`res+= 1<<1;` can be written as `res = res + 1<<1;`
if you take `1<<1` which means `1` is represented as `0x00000001 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`
 when you do a right shift it becomes `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`

which is `0x00000002` which is `2` in decimal value